# How to change Google Drive Document access to RESTRICTED

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api

My app creates a spreadsheet in google drive and sends the link to the user's email. When user opens the email and clicks on the link, he/she is being redirected to

```
docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"spreadSheetId"
```

and gets access to the generated file. But this file by default is public (to anyone on the internet with the link - General Access) as shown in the picture. How can I change the General Access type to RESTRICTED with node.js and give access to only the specified user?

I use "googleapis" npm package (version 49) and with scopes:

1. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
2. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

[image]

Comment: Are these threads useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/62781690 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/73815095

Comment: Dear Tanaike, thanks for your help, but they just add new users to share list. But I need to make the file itself restricted after sharing it with the specified user.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `But I need to make the file itself restricted after sharing it with the specified user.`, how about using contentRestrictions (`Restrictions for accessing the content of the file. Only populated if such a restriction exists.`) to the file? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files) But, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your actual expected result. If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [permissions create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions/create) method to grant a user access to a file rather then making the file public.

It should be something like this.  Let me know if it doesnt work I didnt have time to test it.

```
const emails = ['SomeEmail@gmail.com', ];
for (let i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
  const res = await drive.permissions
    .create({
      resource: {
        role: "writer",
        type: "user",
        emailAddress: emails[i],
      },
      fileId: fileId,
      sendNotificationEmail: true,
      fields: "id",
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err.errors));
  if (res) console.log(res.data);
}
```

Comment: Dear Linda, thanks for you answer, I tried it, but it adds new user to share list only. It doesn't change the access type to RESTRICT. After your proposed code I need to make another query that will change the access.

Comment: do a permission list what is it showing?  can you remove the one that's public

Comment: Getting 2 permissions. 1 is Owner, other one is the one I specified in the code. I can give  Owner role to the specified user and remove the other one. But getting error: The transferOwnership parameter must be enabled when the permission role is 'owner'. How to pass it?

Comment: const grantedPermission = await this.driveService.permissions.create({
                    resource: {
                        role: 'owner',
                        type: 'user',
                        emailAddress: 'user@email.com'
                    },
                    fileId,
                    sendNotificationEmail: true,
                    fields: 'id'
                });

Comment: I tried to give the Owner role to myself and remove the original owner's permission, but getting this error: RejectionWarning: Error: Bad Request. User message: "Sorry, cannot transfer ownership to user@email.com. Ownership can only be transferred to another user in the same organization as the current owner."

Comment: who created the file?  a service account from workspace?

Comment: Yes, Owner is Google Service Account.

Comment: You need to have the service account transfer the domain.  Are you making changes from the service account?

Comment: Yes, the Owner is Google Service Account, not any domain. And it's shared drive account. Seems that it's impossible. Only via UI, not from api provided by Google packake - "googleapis"

Answer (score 0):

To change the file general access from `Anyone with the link` to `Restricted`, you can use the `permissions.delete` method.

I can't test with node.js at the moment but based on samples, the request would look like this:

```
drive.permissions
  .delete({
    fileId: fileId, 
    permissionId: "anyoneWithLink"
  }
```

Also in your comments I see that you have issues transferring ownership of a file due to error `"Sorry, cannot transfer ownership to user@email.com. Ownership can only be transferred to another user in the same organization as the current owner."`

This behavior is due to how Google Drive Works since you cannot transfer the file ownership to a different domain.

> Known limitations and alternatives
>
> You can't transfer ownership to or from an external user, such as a personal Google Account or a user in another organization. This limitation is to protect user and company data from unauthorized transfer and access. Depending on your organization’s sharing policies, you may be able to use the following alternatives.

**UPDATE**

If the file is owned by a service account, the same applies, the file can't be transferred to another user since a service account is not considered as a domain user.

As a workaround, you can create a `Shared Drive`, add the service account and the other user that you want to make the new owner with `organizer` role and this will allow the user to move the file from the Shared Drive to his drive making him the owner of the file.

Another workaround would be to make a copy of the file, as I understand the file is already shared with the other user, so in this case the user can make a copy of the file and later you can delete the original file from the service account.

**Suggestions:**

To avoid this problem in the future you can use impersonation, this means that the service account acts on behalf of the user and when he uploads the file it is equivalent as the domain user is doing the action, there is no need to transfer ownership as he would be the owner of the file. You can find more information in the references below.

## References

- [Method: permissions.delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions/delete)
- [Transfer Drive files to a new owner as an admin](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1247799#:%7E:text=Drive%20log%20events.-,Known%20limitations%20and%20alternatives,-You%20can%E2%80%99t%20transfer)
- [Service accounts and Google Workspace domains](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-overview#domains)
- [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)

Comment: Thanks Lorena. I tested with "anyoneWithLink" param, but getting error:  Error: Permission not found: anyoneWithLink.

Comment: Test this [method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions/list?apix_params=%7B%22fileId%22%3A%22fileId%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22*%22%7D), just add your file ID to the request and let me know what is the response?

Comment: I'm getting 2 permissions with id, kind, role, type. Both types are user and 1 with role "owner", another one with "writer". kind is "drive#permission" and each has different permission id.

Comment: Based on the response that you get then it seems that the file is not shared with "Anyone with the link", also I have updated my answer regarding the error that you get when trying to transfer a file

Comment: @RufatGulabli did my answer work for you (at least for your initial concern)?

Comment: Lorena, thanks for your help, but it did not. The problem was solved just removing the code. "await gsheets.permission(spreadsheetId);"

Comment: @RufatGulabli I don't think you have shared your code in the question, therefore no one could have ever determined that this was the correct answer.

Comment: @Lorena, yes you're right. But I can't share the code due to company policy. Anyway, thanks for your help. Much appreciated. I learned a lot from your comments.

Answer (score -2):

The issue was that by default the access was Restricted, but there was a line of code that made it Globally accessible.

> await gsheets.permission(spreadsheetId);

I realized that this line of code creates a permission with role like "anyOneWithLink", but it's not returned when I made a request to Google in order to get the list of permissions and delete the required one. I just removed this line of code and wrote a code to add permission to the required users - who makes the request.

Again thanks to all who helped me to understand how it works and find what I want.